# TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse some characters:

Tags: javascript, django

A HTML file we're using in out project is working absolutely fine when ran independently but when inserted into DJANGO, this error occurs (it looks a bit over the top but it seems to be a problem with how JS methods/variables must be written in django?):

> TemplateSyntaxError at /rpg/play/
>
> Could not parse some characters:
>
> var| a=i.objectName;i.typeName}return function(){function t(t,n,r){var
>   i=l.children('[data-name="'+t+'"]'),o=a(n);i.length||(i=e('').appendTo(l)),i.empty().append(""+t+(r?""+r+"":"")+""+a(n)+"");var
>   s=l.children();c.text(s.length+"
>   Variable"+(1!==s.length?"s":""))}function i(){var
>   r=[];l.children().each(function(i,o){o=e(o);var
>   s=o.attr("data-name"),u=o.attr("data-value");s.startsWith("TwineScript")||(s
>   in
>   n.variables?(r.push(s),a(n.variables[s])!==u&&t(s,n.variables[s])):o.remove())});for(var
>   i in
>   n.variables)i.startsWith("TwineScript")|||r.includes(i)||t(i,n.variables[i])}var
>   s=e("Turns: Debug
>   View0
>   Variables"),u=s.find(".show-invisibles");u.click(function(){e(document.documentElement).toggleClass("debug-mode"),u.toggleClass("enabled")});var
>   c=s.find(".show-variables"),l=s.find(".variables");c.click(function(){lc.is(".enabled")?"attr":"removeAttr",c.toggleClass("enabled")});var
>   f=s.find("select");f.change(function(e){var
>   t=e.target.value,r=t-n.pastLength;0!==r&&(n0>r?"rewind":"fastForward",o.showPassage(n.passage))}),n.on("forward",function(t){var
>   r=arguments.length>1&&void
>   0!==arguments[1]?arguments[1]:!1,i=n.pastLength;i>1&&f.removeAttr("disabled"),r||(f.children().each(function(t,n){t>=i&&e(n).remove()}),f.append(""+(i+1)+":
>   "+t+"").val(i))}).on("back",function(){n.pastLength<=1&&f.attr("disabled"),f.find("[selected]").removeAttr("selected"),f.val(n.pastLength)}).on("load",function(e){f.empty(),fe.length<=1?"attr":"removeAttr",e.forEach(function(e,t){return
>   f.append(""+(t+1)+":
>   "+e.passage+"")})}),n.on("forward",i).on("back",i),r.on("set",function(e,r,i){(e===n.variables||e.TwineScript_VariableStore)&&t(r,i,e===n.variables?"":e.TwineScript_VariableStoreName)}).on("delete",function(e,t){e===n.variables&&l.find('[data-name="'+t+'"]:not(.temporary)').remove()}),e(document.body).append(s)

Comment: Well `var| a=` is a problem already...

Comment: You need to show the actual template code.

Answer (score 0):

Django didn't like how long an individual line was in the HTML, thus the random "|" symbol. Simply splitting it over an extra line fixed it.